# How to insert / emplace into map to avoid creation of temporary objects?

Tags: c++11, insert, perfect-forwarding, emplace

I'm reading a recommendation from one of C++11 books to prefer `emplace` over `insert` when adding items to the container in order to avoid creation of temporary objects (calls of constructors / destructors of the objects being inserted). But I'm a bit confused because there are a few possibilities how one can add an object to the map, e.g.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdint>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    std::string one     { "one" };
    std::string two     { "two" };

    std::map<uint32_t, std::string> testMap;

    testMap.insert(std::make_pair(1, one));         // 1
    testMap.emplace(2, two);                        // 2
    testMap.insert(std::make_pair(3, "three"));     // 3
    testMap.emplace(4, "four");                     // 4

    using valType = std::map < uint32_t, std::string >::value_type;
    testMap.emplace(valType(5, "five"));            // 5
    testMap.insert(valType(6, "six"));              // 6

    return 0;
}
```

There are also some under-the-hood-mechanisms involved which are not immediately visible when reading such a code - perfect forwarding, implicit conversions ...

What is the optimal way of adding items to the map container ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider your options one at a time (plus one or two you haven't mentioned).

Options 1 and 6 are essentially identical as far as semantics go. The `using` and the `pair` are just two different ways of spelling the value_type of the `map`. If you wanted you could add a third way using a `typedef` instead of a `using` statement:

```
typedef std::map<uint32_t, std::string>::value_type valType;
```

...and have a C++98/03 equivalent of your #6. All three end up doing the same thing though: creating a temporary object of the `pair` type, and inserting that into the `map`.

Versions 3 and 5 do pretty much the same. They use `emplace`, but what they pass is already an object of the `map`'s value_type. By the time `emplace` itself starts to execute, the type of object that will be stored in the map has already been constructed. Again, the only difference between the two is in the syntax used to specify that `pair` type--and, again, with a `typedef` like I've shown above, you could have a C++98/03 equivalent of the one that currently has the `using` statement. The fact that version 3 uses `insert` and version 5 uses `emplace` makes almost no real difference--by the time either member function is invoked, we've already created and passed a temporary object.

Options 2 and 4 both actually use `emplace` more like it was probably intended--passing individual components, perfect-forwarding them to the constructor, and constructing a `value_type` object in-place, so we avoid creating any temporary objects at any point. The primary (sole?) difference between the two of them is in whether the thing we pass for the `string` component of the value_type is a string literal (from which a temporary `std::string` object needs to be created) or a `std::string` object that was created ahead of time.

The choice between those could be non-trivial. If (as above) you're only doing it once, it won't really make any difference at all--regardless of *when* you create it, you're creating a string object, then putting it into the `map`.

So, to make a real difference, we need to pre-create the string object, then repeatedly insert that same string object into the `map`. That's pretty unusual in itself--in most cases, you're going to do something like read external data into a string, then insert that into the `map`. If you really do insert (an `std::string` constructed from) the same string literal repeatedly, chances are pretty good that any reasonable compiler can detect that the resulting string is loop-invariant, and hoist the `string` construction out of the loop, giving essentially the same effect.

Bottom line: as far as the use of `map` itself goes, choices 2 and 4 are equivalent. Between those two, I wouldn't go to any real effort to use option 2 over option 4 (i.e., pre-creating the string) but it's likely to happen most of the time, simply because inserting a single string literal into a map is rarely useful. The string you put in a map will much more frequently come from some external data source, so you'll have a `string` because that's what (for example) `std::getline` gave you when you read the data from the file.